# Permutations of Digits in Python

Tags: python, string, permutation

I have the four digit permutations of digits 0-9, and all of these are stored in a big list.
`(0, 1, 2, 3)(0, 1, 2, 4)(0, 1, 2, 5)(0, 1, 2, 6), etc`.

But! I want these to be stored differently. I want `0123, 0124, 0125, 1026, etc`. How can I change make each item in the list join into a single item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * 10 + y, (0, 1, 2, 3))
123

>>> '%04d' % (reduce(lambda x, y: x * 10 + y, (0, 1, 2, 3)),)
'0123'
```

Comment: This does work, but would you mind explaining it? Using the lists I provided above, it beings outputting 3 digit numbers before it gets to the four digit permutations.

Comment: It takes the sequences of integers and puts them in thousands, hundreds, tens, and units position by multiplying the current value by 10 and adding the new value. It outputs three-digit numbers because leading 0s are not printed; use the second if this is a problem, which formats the number as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the "digits" are strings (and not integers), do it like this:

```
result = map(''.join, long_list)
```

Alternatively this will work for strings and integers:

```
result = map('{[0]}{[1]}{[2]}{[3]}'.format, longlist)
```

Or use itertools.imap() for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
[ reduce(lambda x,y: str(x) + str(y), list) for list in lists]
```

Join version:

```
[ reduce(lambda x,y: ''.join((x,y)), map(str,list)) for list in lists]
```

Both versions for integers, if elements are string skip mapping to string :)

Comment: Adding strings like this is O(n**2) on older versions of Python; `''.join()` is a superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension with format:

```
>>> l=[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 5), (0, 1, 2, 6)]
>>> ['{}{}{}{}'.format(*t) for t in l]
['0123', '0124', '0125', '0126']
```

Works for ints or strings in the tuples:

```
>>> l=[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 5), (0, 1, '2', 6)]
>>> ['{}{}{}{}'.format(*t) for t in l]
['0123', '0124', '0125', '0126']
```

If you want ints, you can use map on the output of the LC:

```
>>> map(int,['{}{}{}{}'.format(*t) for t in l])
[123, 124, 125, 126]
```

Use `join` if tuples might be variable length:

```
>>> l=[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 5), (0, 1, '2')]
>>> [''.join(map(str,t)) for t in l]
['0123', '0124', '0125', '012']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [11]: seq = [(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 5), (0, 1, 2, 6)]

In [12]: [''.join(map(str, item)) for item in seq]
Out[12]: ['0123', '0124', '0125', '0126']
```